# Generators of triangulated category and Grothendieck groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, triangulated-categories, grothendieck-rings

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a triangulated category that is generated by one object, say $A$ in the sense that the smallest triangulated subcategory containing $A$ and closed under coproducts and isomorphisms is $\mathcal{T}$ itself. Denote by $K_0(\mathcal{T})$ the Grothendieck group of $\mathcal{T}$. Is $K_0(\mathcal{T})$ generated by the equivalence class of $A$?

Comment: Yes. Also, triangulated subcategories are closed under finite coproducts. Since you stress coproducts, I think you mean infinite ones too. In that case the Grothendieck group is trivial.

Comment: @FernandoMuro I am a little concerned how to generate the shifts of $A$ in the Grothendieck group!!

Comment: Shifting is multiplication by -1.

Comment: @FernandoMuro You mean shifting is the same as taking inverse? Do you have a reference for this or an argument. May be you could give a sketch in the answer.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mean.

Comment: $A\to 0\to A[1] \to A[1]$

Comment: @FernandoMuro Thanks. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fernando Muro has already answered this in the comments, but perhaps a reference would help. This is all spelled out in Neeman's book on triangulated categories. In particular, see Definition 4.5.8 and Proposition 4.5.11, and their proofs.